# Add eventlistener to canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I correctly get `canvas tag` from html but when I try to add  it an eventlistener, console returns me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I can't understand the reason.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
console.log(x); //print correctly the element : [canvas, item: function, namedItem: function]

x.addEventListener("click", prova);//Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

function prova( event ) {

console.log("prova");//


};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]`

`getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection (kind of like an array), and `addEventListener` only works on elements, so you need to select the element with the correct index.

An alternative is `document.querySelector("canvas")` which will return one element.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/4j0fjh6x/

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of HTML elements, therefore you must define an index. In a basic example of HTML you can assume that you only have one `<canvas>` tag, so you can use `getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]`.

Comment: That's what Nick Manning said... ;-)

Comment: fiddles are nice though